# SwiftUI ObservableObject used as EnvironmentObject odd behaviour

Tags: swiftui, combine, observableobject

I have such `ObservableObject` that I am injecting into views hierarchy by using `environmentObject()`.

```
class MenuModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var selection: Int = 0
    @Published var isMenuOpen: Bool = false

    @Published var tabItems : [TabItem] = [TabItem]()
//    {
//        didSet {
//            objectWillChange.send()
//        }
//    }
    @Published var menuItems : [MenuItem] = [MenuItem]()
//    {
//        didSet {
//            objectWillChange.send()
//        }
//    }

    //var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
}
```

And here are issues I do not really understand well: 
1. Above code with works correctly, as all properties are @Published. 
2. But If I change it to something like this

```
class Click5MenuModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var selection: Int = 0
    @Published var isMenuOpen: Bool = false

    var tabItems : [TabItem] = [TabItem]()
    {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    var menuItems : [MenuItem] = [MenuItem]()
    {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
}
```

Then @Published properties stop refreshing Views that depends on this ObservableObject! 
Why is that. I also tried to add `didSet` with `objectWillChange.send()` but this also causes some odd behaviour and code is a little bit awkward.

Does this mean that I can only use **ONLY @Published** or **ONLY  objectWillChange** approach?

Comment: Do you want just to know the reason or how to make it work? Because by my tests removing your locally defined `objectWillChange` and use instead inherited from `ObservableObject` in `didSet`, ie. `didSet { self.objectWillChange.send() }` updates view as expected. Just in case.

Comment: objectWillChange is my locally define? so I shouldn't place it at all? I added this as most examples use it, but as you say I should only call it in didSet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default implementation just works (whenever you have @Published properties). Here is from API declaration:

> ```
> /// By default an `ObservableObject` will synthesize an `objectWillChange`
> /// publisher that emits before any of its `@Published` properties changes:
> ...
> @available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
> extension ObservableObject where Self.ObjectWillChangePublisher == ObservableObjectPublisher {
>
>     /// A publisher that emits before the object has changed.
>     public var objectWillChange: ObservableObjectPublisher { get }
> }
> ```

so remove the following:

```
var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
```

and use

```
didSet {
    self.objectWillChange.send()
}
```

Comment: I think you have to expect odd behavio(u)r when using `didSet` instead of `willSet` to call `objectWillChange`. Useful discussion here: https://www.pointfree.co/blog/posts/30-swiftui-and-state-management-corrections